# mkdir works from command line but fails in C++ when using NFS

Tags: c++, mkdir, nfs

I have a group of servers and we are using NFS to mount the drives from each server on all of the others. We were able to mount the drives without any issue. I can call mkdir from the command line onto one of the nfs mounted drives and everything works properly. But if I try to run mkdir from a program written in C. It says that the file or directory does not exist when we try to run mkdir. It is not trying to create multiple levels of directories or anything like that. It is trying in the exact same place with the exact same privileges but for some reason when we call mkdir from C it gives the message that the file does not exist (I am assuming it means the parent directory).

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <string.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cerrno>

#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  // O_RDONLY
#include <unistd.h> // read
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>



    #define FILE_PERMISSION_BITS_MODE 0700
    int makeDir(std::string folderPath){

        bool dirExists = false;
        int success = -1;
        struct stat sb;
        if (stat(folderPath.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
            dirExists = true;
            success = 0;
        }

        if (!dirExists){
            int success = mkdir(folderPath.c_str(),FILE_PERMISSION_BITS_MODE);

            int countInvalids = 0;

            while (success != 0 ){

                if (success == -1 && stat(folderPath.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){ // if failed, check again if it exists or not
                    success = 0;
                    break;
                }

                int fileRetryDelay = 20;
                const int sleep_milliseconds = (countInvalids+1)*fileRetryDelay;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_milliseconds));

                if (countInvalids % 5 == 0){
                    const std::string sysError(std::strerror(errno));

                    std::cout<<"ERROR: FileUtil::makeDir failed to make directory: " << folderPath<<" try number "<<countInvalids << "   Error was: "<< sysError << " (" << errno << ")"<<std::endl;
                }
                countInvalids++;

                success = mkdir(folderPath.c_str(),FILE_PERMISSION_BITS_MODE);

                if (countInvalids > 10000){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (success == 0 && countInvalids > 0){
                std::cout<<"FileUtil::makeDir finally succeeded making directory: " << folderPath << "   Succeeded after "<<countInvalids<<" tries"<<std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (success == -1 && stat(folderPath.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){ // if failed, check again if it exists or not
            success = 0;
        }

        return success;

    }


int main(){
     makeDir("/some/path");
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the failing program and show us?

Comment: How can we answer this without the line of code that supposedly creates the directory?

Comment: The command line "mkdir" is written in C. Your own implementation is probably wrong, or you compare 2 executions in 2 different contexts.

Comment: I j ust added the code that makes the directory.  It rerally is quite simple the line that is failing is  success = mkdir(folderPath.c_str(),FILE_PERMISSION_BITS_MODE); Because sometimes NFS fails but actually ends up creating the directory we also check to see if it exists after every creation attempt.

Comment: There is one problem in your code: You don't check or save the value of `errno` when you're supposed to. You need to check (or save) the value of `errno` *immediately* after the failing function. Otherwise the value of `errno` might become undefined on POSIX systems.

Comment: Ok I can rework that but I am pretty sure I will get the exact same value. Thank you for the information though that is good to know.

Comment: This is **not** C. Retagged to C++, you might have better chances that someone can see something in this code over there.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I forgot to add the ++.

Comment: You realise you have two instances of `success`? The inner one masks the outer one...

Comment: I do now. Even so this would  not be an issue in this particular case because the directory does not exist beforehand. What I am really trying to understand is that under what circumstances can mkdir called from c++ exhibit different behaviour than mkdir on the command line given the same user, same permissions, and trying to create the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

So after some digging we figured out what was going on.

1. We needed to be capturing the errno right after the call as was mentioned because the errno being captured a few ms later was not the same.
2. When using NFS and running an application as root you need to use the option no_root_squash in order to be able to write to the filesystem you  are accessing.

Instead of using the option no_root_squash, which is insecure for obvious reasons, we made sure that our application was not running under sudo or by the root user.